# Storefront api not showing changes on checkout page, want to remove auto apply of store credit on my bigcommerce store

Tags: e-commerce, bigcommerce

I have 2 storefronts and I want users to use store credit only on one storefront so I want to disable the auto application of store credit on the checkout page but I couldn't find any option for that. So I ran the Remove store credit storefront API It gave a 200 response but I can't see the changes on my store view, if I reload my page B2B edition runs its script and auto applies store credit again. but even if I run storefront API in the console it still show any change on checkout page view.

I have tried custom script to remove store credit using storefront api
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-storefront/checkouts/checkout-store-credit#remove-store-credit
my scripts run and the strefront api gives 200 satus but still its not changing on the checkout page and also added it as defer script.
I tried to customize b2b edition script also